# Kubernetes) subdirectories not mounted when creating pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am working with kubernetes. I want to mount the local(host) volume in the container.

But it doesn't mount the subdirectories inside the directory.

This is my job.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: ts-engine
spec:
    containers:
    - image: ts_engine:latest
      name: ts-engine
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c","cd workspace && ls && echo '1234'&& cd .. && ls"]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /workspace
        name: workspace
    volumes:
    - name: workspace
      hostPath:
        path: /workspace
        type: Directory
```

The logs for this pod are like this:

```
1234
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
workspace
```

It shows that the "workspace" directory is empty but actually it has some directories in "workspace".

Is there any idea for this situation?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? How did you deploy your cluster?

Comment: `hostPath:` mounts a directory from the node the pod is running on, which could be different nodes for multiple replicas or if a pod gets deleted; you usually don't want it.  There's no way to mount your local system's disk into a Kubernetes cluster (except in specific local-only developer-oriented setups).

Comment: I used " kubectl apply -f job.yaml " to deploy my cluster.

Comment: @DavidMaze Did you mean that "hostPath" is used between kubernetes nodes? Then there is no way to mount my local directory to my pod?

Comment: I am asking about how did you deploy you cluster, not a pod. Did you use some cloud providor or bare metal installation?

Comment: I used my ubuntu server not cloud. Yeah that is bare metal installation

Comment: I need to know how exactly did you setup your cluster? Did you use Minikube or some other solution? Please attach to the question steps as you have created your cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of your "ls" command shows that you are not actually working in the directory "workspace".  You are at the top level (/), and are listing the directory not its contents.  In other words, your cd command isn't doing what you think.

To really be able to answer this, we would need to know more about your setup, but here is my best guess:

- You are probably running Minikube, or some other local kubernetes cluster.
- This runs it its own virtual machine, which does not have access to the directories on your local machine by default
- As @David Maze noted, hostPath: mounts a directory from the local node, so this is only really usable if you are running kubernetes locally in development
- Your Kubernetes cluster is probably in an isolated virtual machine, so the mount fails